# How to select range of cells from cells having mentioned string to next cell having the mentioned string in a Dataframe, Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

[image: Enter data]

select range of cells from  cells having mentioned string to next cell having the mentioned string in a Dataframe

Comment: Very unclear of what you are trying to say..

Answer (score 0):

Example dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'text': 'a,start,b,c,d,end,x,y,z,start,q,w,e,r,end,t,e,w'.split(',')
})
```

Solution:

```py
pd.concat([
    df[s:e+1] for s,e in zip(
        df[df['text'] == 'start'].index,
        df[df['text'] == 'end'].index)])
```

Before and After:

[image: Before]
[image: After]

That's if you really want to do it in pure pandas. Unless you want to support overlapping sequences (the above solution does), I would go for a simple iteration, to be honest:

```py
writing = False
result = []
for i, token in df['text'].iteritems():
    if token == 'start':
        writing = True
    if writing:
        result.append(i)
    if token == 'end':
        writing = False
df.loc[result]
```

Comment: Thanks Rudolfovic  :)  This solves my query

Comment: Glad to help, consider accepting and upvoting :)